# All possible exit codes for cp

Tags: linux, unix, exit-code, cp

Looking at the man pages for cp, I only found that the command exits with 0 when copy succeeds with no error, and with a number greater than 0 on any error. However I couldn't find any detailed description on specific exit codes mapped to specific cases. Is there such a description anywhere, is it even standardized, or each Unix/Linux distribution has its own exit code set for different scenarios?

Comment: 99% of Unix commands just use 0 for success, 1 for failure, they don't have different codes to distinguish the reasons. The few commands that have specific exit codes describe them in their man pages. So if it doesn't have this detail, you can assume there's no specific codes.

Comment: For an example of this, see the `grep` man page. The exit code is `0` if matches were found, `1` if no matches were found, `2` if an error occurred.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is how `cp` from `coreutils-8.21` exits:

```
exit (ok ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
```

There's nothing else than 0 or 1.

Comment: And even if there were a more sophisticated distinction, it would be valid for this one implementation only. If it is not described in any standard, it is not present in a portable way.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac (10.12.5 (16F73)) there are additional codes. For instance:

```
Mac$ cp -W 1 2; echo $?
cp: illegal option -- W
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
64
```